# Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list' on confusionMatrix()

Tags: r, dataframe, confusion-matrix

I have this problem and I don't understand why does it happens. I checked lot of post and tried lot of solution such as `unlist` but, it doesn't seem to want to work ..

Since it's for an homework, I deleted some parts, but I let the main part:

```
my_svm <- function(df, alpha, degree, cost)
{

  mylist = partition(df, alpha)

  df1 = mylist[[1]]
  df2 = mylist[[2]]

  ...

  lastColName <- colnames(df)[ncol(df)]

  ...

  model <- svm(as.formula(paste(lastColName, "~ .", sep = " ")),
                   data = df1,
                   kernel="polynomial",
                   degree = degree,
                   type = "C-classification",
                   cost = cost)

  a = confusionMatrix(df1[,-ncol(df1)], model)

  ...

}
```

However, it keep saying that `Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?`

Why? either if I use `unlist` or the proper name, it keeps happening... I really don't get why..

Thank in advance for any help

### update

```
    `List of 2

    $ :'data.frame':    1382 obs. of  7 variables:
    ..$ buying  : Factor w/ 4 levels "high","low","med",..: 4 1 2 4 4 2 4 3 3 2     ...
  ..$ maint   : Factor w/ 4 levels "high","low","med",..: 2 2 3 1 4 4 4 3 4 4 ...
  ..$ doors   : Factor w/ 4 levels "2","3","4","5more": 2 3 1 1 1 2 4 3 3 3 ...
  ..$ persons : Factor w/ 3 levels "2","4","more": 2 2 1 2 3 3 3 3 3 1 ...
  ..$ lug_boot: Factor w/ 3 levels "big","med","small": 3 3 3 2 1 2 2 1 2 3 ...
  ..$ safety  : Factor w/ 3 levels "high","low","med": 3 3 1 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ class   : Factor w/ 4 levels "acc","good","unacc",..: 3 3 3 3 3 1 3 4 1 3 ...
    $ :'data.frame':    346 obs. of  7 variables:
     ..    $ buying  : Factor w/ 4 levels "high","low","med",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4       ...
      ..    $ maint   : Factor w/ 4 levels "high","low","med",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
    ..    $ doors   : Factor w/ 4 levels "2","3","4","5more": 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 ...
    ..    $ persons : Factor w/ 3 levels "2","4","more": 1 1 2 2 3 2 2 2 3 1 ...
    ..    $ lug_boot: Factor w/ 3 levels "big","med","small": 2 1 3 1 2 3 3 3 3 3 ...
    ..    $ safety  : Factor w/ 3 levels "high","low","med": 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 1 3 1 ...
    ..    $ class   : Factor w/ 4 levels "acc","good","unacc",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...`
```

### Update 2

```
List of 30
 $ call           : language svm(formula = as.formula(paste(lastColName, "~ .", sep = " ")), data = df1, kernel = "polynomial", degree = degree,      type = "C-classification", cost = cost)
 $ type           : num 0
 $ kernel         : num 1
 $ cost           : num 0.1
 $ degree         : num 1
 $ gamma          : num 0.0625
 $ coef0          : num 0
 $ nu             : num 0.5
 $ epsilon        : num 0.1
 $ sparse         : logi FALSE
 $ scaled         : logi [1:16] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ x.scale        : NULL
 $ y.scale        : NULL
 $ nclasses       : int 4
 $ levels         : chr [1:4] "acc" "good" "unacc" "vgood"
 $ tot.nSV        : int 731
 $ nSV            : int [1:4] 308 315 47 61
 $ labels         : int [1:4] 1 3 4 2
 $ SV             : num [1:731, 1:16] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:731] "368" "1478" "1067" "1049" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:16] "buyinghigh" "buyinglow" "buyingmed" "buyingvhigh" ...
 $ index          : int [1:731] 1 6 7 17 22 35 36 38 40 44 ...
 $ rho            : num [1:6] 1.04 -1.02 -1.03 -1.03 -1.08 ...
 $ compprob       : logi FALSE
 $ probA          : NULL
 $ probB          : NULL
 $ sigma          : NULL
 $ coefs          : num [1:731, 1:3] 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 ...
 $ na.action      : NULL
 $ fitted         : Factor w/ 4 levels "acc","good","unacc",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:1382] "368" "382" "577" "13" ...
 $ decision.values: num [1:1382, 1:6] -0.86 -1.398 -1.101 -1.274 -0.916 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:1382] "368" "382" "577" "13" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "acc/unacc" "acc/vgood" "acc/good" "unacc/vgood" ...
 $ terms          :Classes 'terms', 'formula'  language class ~ buying + maint + doors + persons + lug_boot + safety
  .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(class, buying, maint, doors, persons, lug_boot, safety)
  .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:7, 1:6] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:7] "class" "buying" "maint" "doors" ...
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "buying" "maint" "doors" "persons" ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr [1:6] "buying" "maint" "doors" "persons" ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int [1:6] 1 1 1 1 1 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= num 0
  .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
  .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: 0x0000000019274010> 
  .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(class, buying, maint, doors, persons, lug_boot, safety)
  .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:7] "factor" "factor" "factor" "factor" ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:7] "class" "buying" "maint" "doors" ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "svm.formula" "svm"
```

Comment: could you post the structure of `mylist` using this command `str(mylist)`?

Comment: is `confusionMatrix` from library `caret`?

Comment: Yep it is from the caret library

Comment: Please try this and see if you get the same error `confusionMatrix( model, df1[[ ncol(df1) ]] )`

Comment: same error.....

Comment: please post `str(model)`. the variable model should have factor levels of columns except the last one

Comment: you could simply verify it by checking its class using `class(model)`. It should return factor

Comment: I see the problem now. You fit the model, but never used `predict` to get the prediction. With the prediction, you can create a confusionMatrix. The package `e1071` offers a predict method for svm model. Please read `?confusionMatrix` for more info. Hope this helps

Comment: use the examples in `?confusionMatrix` to understand how to fit, predict and then create confusionMatrix